# C++: why can a function declaration not assign a name to it's argument(s)?

Tags: c++, function, types, arguments

For example, this code: `double sqrt(double) { return 0; }` is apparently completely fine. It takes one argument of type double. But there is no way to use that argument in any way because it wasn't assigned a name, so there's nothing to call it by. What's the point of having that argument there then?

Comment: This is how you suppress the "unused variable" warnings and also make your intention very clears

Comment: In case of a class method it is a way of constraining future function override.

Comment: `But there is no way to use that argument`. Yes there is. Give it a name!